# return the object as per custom weight in ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, hash

I have a use case where I have the array of object and I want to return the particular object based on the type. But the interesting part is that if one type is present then it should return the specific object and if it is not present it should return the object which has 2nd type and so on.

For me, priority is if **type: video** is present is should be returned and if it is not present then it should check further for **type: file**, if it is present then object with **type:file** should returned.

```
Ex: a = [<id:1, type:'video', format:'mp4'>, <id:2, type:'audio', format:'mp3'>,
         <id:3, type:'file', format:'txt'>, <id:4, type:'exe', format:'exe'>]
```

In response, I should get the object of **index 0** if **type: video** is present in **a**, else it should return object of **index 2** if **type: file** is present and then it should return object of index 1.

Comment: I am considering to use hash with weights in the value.
OBJ_SEQ ={
    :video => 0,
    :file => 1,
    :exe => 2
  }
and then use some logic but still not able to figure it out.

Comment: Why are you using a version of Ruby on Rails that has been unmaintained for several years and has unpatched security vulnerabilities? That is a very bad idea!

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation @JörgWMittag. I would definitely update the version first.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `enum` for solving this:

```
Class YourModel
  enum type: %i[video file exe]

end
```

And then your query can be sorted based on type like this:

```
YourModel.order(type: :asc).first
```

Comment: I want to have a method in model to get the object out of this array. Can you please assist me with the code of method as well. Actually I am new to ruby.

Comment: undefined method `enum' for <NyModel>:Class (NoMethodError) getting this error in model class.

Comment: which version of rails are you on?

Comment: Enums are supported since version Rails 4.1

Comment: ruby version is 3.01 and rails is 6+.